# SQL Server get string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two rows like below, from that I need to fetch the previous string in the select. e.g in the first row I need to fetch 'Auto Components', in the second row I need to fetch 'Plastic and Synthetic Resins'. Please suggest.

```
Automotive > Auto Components > Auto Parts and Equipment
Chemicals > Commodity Chemicals > Plastic and Synthetic Resins > Plastic Products
```

Comment: Use the `REVERSE` function to reverse the string, look for the first occurrence of`>` and substring everything after it (throw away everything before it) using `RIGHT` or `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`, look again for the first occurrence of `>` in this new substring, and remove everything after it (`LEFT` or `SUBSTRING`). Finally, reverse the string again. Alternatively, `CHARINDEX` takes a parameter of where to start searching if you want to only do one substring operation - start searching at the index of the first `>` when you're looking for the second `>`

Answer (score 0):

For more info, see my comment:

```
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(rs, firstangle + 1, secondangle - firstangle - 1))
FROM
(
  SELECT CHARINDEX('>', rs) as firstangle, CHARINDEX('>', rs,  CHARINDEX('>', rs)+1) as secondangle, rs, s
  FROM
  (
    SELECT REVERSE(s) as rs, s
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 'Chemicals > Commodity Chemicals > Plastic and Synthetic Resins > Plastic Products' as s
    ) a
  ) b
)c
```

I did this as several subqueries because it makes it a bit neater than trying to do it all in one go..

All in one looks more like this hideous thing:

```
    SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(s), CHARINDEX('>', REVERSE(s)) + 1, CHARINDEX('>', REVERSE(s),  CHARINDEX('>', REVERSE(s))+1) - CHARINDEX('>', REVERSE(s)) - 1))
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 'Chemicals > Commodity Chemicals > Plastic and Synthetic Resins > Plastic Products' as s
    ) a
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `PARSENAME()` function if you are working with `SQL Server 2012` or above

```
SELECT LTRIM(PARSENAME(REPLACE(data, '>', '.'), 2)) FROM <table_name>
```

else you could use conditional `substring()` & `charindex()` function method

```
SELECT CASE (A.RN)
           WHEN 1
           THEN SUBSTRING(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(DATA, CHARINDEX('>', DATA)+1, LEN(DATA))), 1 , CHARINDEX('>', LTRIM(SUBSTRING(DATA, CHARINDEX('>', DATA)+1, LEN(DATA))))-2)
           WHEN 2
           THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(DATA, CHARINDEX('>', DATA)+2, LEN(DATA)), CHARINDEX('>', SUBSTRING(DATA, CHARINDEX('>', DATA)+1, LEN(DATA))), LEN(DATA)), 1, CHARINDEX('>', LTRIM(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(DATA, CHARINDEX('>', DATA)+2, LEN(DATA)), CHARINDEX('>', SUBSTRING(DATA, CHARINDEX('>', DATA)+1, LEN(DATA))), LEN(DATA))))))
       END [DATA]
FROM
(
    SELECT DATA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) RN FROM <table_name>
) A;
```

Result :

```
Auto Components
Plastic and Synthetic Resins
```